# Shard/mod function

Tags: python

Let's say I have `n` machines and I need to allocate data across those machines as uniformly as possible. Let's use `5` for this example. And the data we have will look like:

```
id        state           name              date
1         'DE'            'Aaron'           2014-01-01
```

To shard on the id, I could do a function like:

```
machine_num = id % n
```

To shard on a string, I suppose the most basic way would be something like string-to-binary-to-number:

```
name_as_num = int(''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in name), 2)
machine_num = name_as_num % n
```

Or even simpler:

```
machine_num = ord(name[0]) % n
```

What would be an example of how a date or timestamp could be sharded? And what might be a better function to shard a string (or even numeric) field than the ones I'm using above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further knowledge about the structure and distribution about the keys used for shard operations, a hash function is a good approach. Python standard library provides in [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) module the simple functions `adler32` and `crc32` which take bytes (actually anything with buffer interface) and return an unsigned 32 bit integer on which modulo can then be applied to get the machine number.

CRC and Adler are fast algorithms but documentation says that "Since the algorithm is designed for use as a checksum algorithm, it is not suitable for use as a general hash algorithm." So the distribution may not be optimal (uniform).

Cryptographic hashes (slower but with better distribution) are available through [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) module. They return their digest as byte-sequence which can be converted to integer with [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).

Answer (score 3):

Since hash functions are meant to produce numbers that are evenly distributed, you can use the hash function for your purpose:

```
machine_num = hash(name) % n
```

Works for `datetime` objects too:

```
machine_num = hash(datetime(2019, 10, 2, 12, 0, 0)) % n
```

But as @jasonharper pointed out in the comment, the hash value of a specific object is only guaranteed to be consistent within the same run of a program, so if you require the distribution to be consistent across multiple runs, you would have to write your own hashing function like what you have done in your question.

Comment: This should be written as `hash(name) % n` - `__hash__()` is how you *implement* hashing for objects, not how you request it.  Also note that the hash value is only guaranteed to be consistent within a single run of your program, it can and will change over multiple runs.

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @jasonharper what about a hash function with persistence/consistency between runs?

Comment: @David542 There are adler32 and crc32 in zlib and cryptographic hashes in hashlib.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for that. Do you want to perhaps add an answer with an example of using those?